# What are options for finishing cement block walls?

Tags: drywall, cement

Our basement and foundation is cement blocks. What are my options for finishing the walls? I can't put drywall directly on the wall correct? Would i have to fur out the wall?

Its a cabin, so is wood paneling an option? just not sure with the cement block walls what the moisture situation would be with covering them.

Comment: Do you want to also add some insulation or not?

Comment: Tell us something about your climate.

Comment: Central Wisconsin. Really cold in the winter. Hot in the summer. Best of both worlds :)

Comment: Are the walls above ground or in a basement. The reason is: basement walls need to breathe and evaporate to the inside. Sealing them to prevent vapor exchange is not a good idea and not usually successful.  Above ground can evaporate to the outside so they are a different situation.

Comment: The first question should about the exterior grade. If your slope is insufficient, it won't matter what you use, it'll still get wet. If your slope is adequate, it may only matter, is the most extreme of cases. I've seen bare block, stay dry for decades, and properly sealed, stay continuously damp, moldy, and efflorescent - water will find a way, if you give it a chance.

Comment: I would agree it depends if above grade or below grade and if below grade the water table issues. I rarely see below grade block walls that are truly dry and when I was back east where block walls below grade was common I never found a sealer that worked on the inside with heavy rains. Above grade block is much easier to seal because the moisture won't have hydraulic pressure pushing the moisture through the smallest cracks in the mortar joints.

Answer (score 1):

I would seal the blocks first using a penetrating waterproofing sealer.  Silane/Siloxane sealers are excellent choices for basement concrete block.   Okon’s S-40, Diamond Hard and Lithi-Tek LS 9500 are some excellent products.  Stay away from latex based sealers.  I would also fur out the walls so I could add some insulation, run electrical, cable, internet and plumbing. You can now finish the walls however you chose.